# String matching by contents of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, keyword, matching

I have a huge data frame and several key words (all non numeric). I want to write R code to go over the whole data frame and look for the columns where the sentences contain one or more of these key words. Then if there was a match to put the key words in the same row in a new column (if more than one matching put them both separated by a comma or in a new column as well).

for instance, given the data below I want to add a column that shows what is matching from these key words:

```
keywords<- c("Smith", "Carla")
```

Then I want the results to look something like this:

```
**Names**          **Matching**

John Smith          Smith
Carla Smith         Carla, Smith **(could be same column or different column)**
Smith Smith         Smith
John Carla          Carla
```

I tried using `grep`:

```
 Matching <- Data[grepl("carla",Data$Names), ]
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Check for `str_extract_all` from `stringr` with `paste`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer has two parts: OP edited his answer, but first part still seems useful

### Part 1: OP's original question

it usually helps to break down your taks in smaller ones and provide a minimal example.

So here's some data

```
shoes <- c("cookie", "nike", "adidas")
drinks <- c("water", "lemon", "cookie")
clothes <- c("pants", "cookie", "sweater")
df <- data.frame(shoes, drinks, clothes, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
```

Now let's go with @akrun's comment and just try and see whether we can get the string "cookie" from a single column:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all("cookie", df$shoes) == "cookie"
```

So, that works, now we need to do it for all columns. To help us on the way we write a small function and loop that over the columns:

```
extract_cookie <- function(x) {
    x <- as.character(x) # just to safeguard against non-string values .
    str_extract_all("cookie", x) == "cookie"
}
sapply(df, extract_cookie)
     shoes drinks clothes
[1,]  TRUE  FALSE   FALSE
[2,] FALSE  FALSE    TRUE
[3,] FALSE   TRUE   FALSE
```

### Part 2: (after OP's edited the question)

Since you now mention your own efforts using `grepl`..

```
people <- c("John Smith", "Carla Smith", "Smith Smith", "John Carla")
persons <- data.frame(people, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

persons$smiths <- grepl("Smith", persons$people)
persons$carlas <- grepl("Carla", persons$people)
persons$perfectMatch <- persons$smiths == TRUE & persons$carlas == TRUE

persons$smiths2 <- ifelse(grepl("Smith", persons$people), "Smiths", "")
persons$carlas2 <- ifelse(grepl("Carla", persons$people), "Carla", "")
persons$perfectMatch2 <- ifelse(persons$perfectMatch == TRUE, 
                                    paste(persons$carlas2, persons$smiths2), "")
persons

       people smiths carlas perfectMatch smiths2 carlas2 perfectMatch2
1  John Smith   TRUE  FALSE        FALSE  Smiths                      
2 Carla Smith   TRUE   TRUE         TRUE  Smiths   Carla  Carla Smiths
3 Smith Smith   TRUE  FALSE        FALSE  Smiths                      
4  John Carla  FALSE   TRUE        FALSE           Carla
```

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question since it wasn't clear enough, all the best!

Comment: Thank you Richard, that was so helpful from you,
All the best!

Comment: Dear Wiam, glad to be of help. if this answers your question, would you please vote it and accept it as the correct answer? (Vote for it by clicking on the triangle pointing upwards, and accept it by clicking the 'check mark' below that)